# Ubuntu doesn't recognize keyboard on latest Macbook

Tags: 16.04, 17.04, macbook-pro

I have a bootable USB stick with ubuntu on it (I have tried both ubuntu 16.04.3 and ubuntu 17.04).

When I boot on my usb key and chose to install ubuntu, I get a page where I have to chose my language. But I can't do anything on this screen: my keyboard doesn't work and my touchpad neither. I don't have a mouse or a usb-keyboard and don't really want to buy one just for that..

I have the latest Macbook pro with touchbar. After searching my issue online, I understood that maybe it is ubuntu that doesn't know how to handle my keyboard/touchpad as they are new. Yet is there a way to solve it without having to wait for a future version of ubuntu? If not, is there an other linux distribution that would handle my device?